# Sass and webpack - @for loop error

Tags: sass, webpack

Here is my code:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
   .myclass-#{$i} {
      /* ... */
   }
}
```

I'm using `webpack` and I got this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/postcss-loader?pack=cleaner!./path/style.scss
/path/to/my/file/style.scss:649:22: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
    .myclass-#{$i} {
               ^
```

Is there a way to solve it?

I use this config:

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loaders: ["style", "css", "sass", "postcss?pack=cleaner"]
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have style loader and css loader. This caused reprocessing I guess. Remove the style loader, and it should work. At least that was my problem for a similar error